# Why is my Latex enumerate giving me a large gap?

Tags: latex, enumerate

I'm making an exam in LaTex, but for some reason there's a large empty space between the image and the next text in my enumerate environment.

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{tikz}%
\usepackage{enumitem}%
%
%
%
\begin{document}%

\begin{enumerate}
    \item{What is the bitstring of this $4\times 4$ pixel image?\newline
        \phantom{abcdefg}\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.7]
            \path[fill=gray] (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,1) -- (0,1) -- (0,0);
            \path[fill=gray] (0,2) -- (1,2) -- (1,3) -- (0,3) -- (0,2);
            \path[fill=gray] (3,2) -- (4,2) -- (4,3) -- (3,3) -- (3,2);
            \path[fill=gray] (2,2) -- (3,2) -- (3,3) -- (2,3) -- (2,2);
            \path[fill=gray] (1,2) -- (2,2) -- (2,3) -- (1,3) -- (1,2);
            \path[fill=gray] (2,1) -- (3,1) -- (3,2) -- (2,2) -- (2,1);
            \path[fill=gray] (2,3) -- (3,3) -- (3,4) -- (2,4) -- (2,3);
            \path[fill=gray] (3,3) -- (4,3) -- (4,4) -- (3,4) -- (3,3);
            \path[fill=gray] (2,0) -- (3,0) -- (3,1) -- (2,1) -- (2,0);
            \foreach \i in {0,...,4}{
                \draw [thin,black] (\i,0) -- (\i,4)  node [above] at (\i,-10){};
                \draw [thin,black] (0,\i) -- (4,\i)  node [above] at (\i,-10){};}
        \end{tikzpicture}\begin{enumerate}
            \item{$0011$ $1111$ $0010$ $1010$}
            \item{$0011$ $1111$ $0010$ $1010$}
            \item{$0011$ $1111$ $0010$ $1010$}
            \item{$0011$ $1111$ $0010$ $1010$}
            \item{$0011$ $1111$ $0010$ $1010$}
        \end{enumerate}}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think you have an extra `}` on your `\end{enumerate}}` (though, that's likely not the issue)

Comment: Can you please make a compilable [mre]

Comment: @DillonDavis No, that `}` is to end `\item{`

Comment: @danielradil `\item` does  not have an argument. You should use it like `\item here some text`. The additional `{...}` don't hurt in most cases, but are not necessary either.

Answer (score 0):

The space is so big, because your empty nodes in the foreach loop are so far away from your picture. As these nodes are anyway empty, you can remove them and get the desired bounding box:

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{tikz}%
\usepackage{enumitem}%
%
%
%
\begin{document}%

\begin{enumerate}
    \item What is the bitstring of this $4\times 4$ pixel image?
    
        \begin{tikzpicture}%[scale=.7]
            \path[fill=gray] (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,1) -- (0,1) -- (0,0);
            \path[fill=gray] (0,2) -- (1,2) -- (1,3) -- (0,3) -- (0,2);
            \path[fill=gray] (3,2) -- (4,2) -- (4,3) -- (3,3) -- (3,2);
            \path[fill=gray] (2,2) -- (3,2) -- (3,3) -- (2,3) -- (2,2);
            \path[fill=gray] (1,2) -- (2,2) -- (2,3) -- (1,3) -- (1,2);
            \path[fill=gray] (2,1) -- (3,1) -- (3,2) -- (2,2) -- (2,1);
            \path[fill=gray] (2,3) -- (3,3) -- (3,4) -- (2,4) -- (2,3);
            \path[fill=gray] (3,3) -- (4,3) -- (4,4) -- (3,4) -- (3,3);
            \path[fill=gray] (2,0) -- (3,0) -- (3,1) -- (2,1) -- (2,0);
            \foreach \i in {0,...,4}{
                \draw [thin,black] (\i,0) -- (\i,4);
                \draw [thin,black] (0,\i) -- (4,\i);
            }
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item $0011$ $1111$ $0010$ $1010$ 
            \item $0011$ $1111$ $0010$ $1010$
            \item $0011$ $1111$ $0010$ $1010$
            \item $0011$ $1111$ $0010$ $1010$
            \item $0011$ $1111$ $0010$ $1010$
        \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]